# Compare Jmeter Results using Azure Kusto Queries

Tags: java, azure, jmeter, kql

I am trying to create a Kusto query to compare two Jmeter Results, I already has this query that show me the results for 1 test, But I don't know how to add another one and marge the result.

Attached the Query and and image for reference.

Can Someone help me to complete the Query?

```
let testName = "jmeter";
let TestStartTime = "{Startime}";
requests
| where name == testName
    and customDimensions.TestStartTime == TestStartTime
| summarize
    Samples = count(),
    Average = tolong(avg(duration)),
    (L50, L90, L95, L99)
        = percentiles(duration, 50, 90, 95, 99),
    Min = min(duration),
    Maximum = max(duration),
    ErrorCount = countif(success == false),
    StartTime = min(tolong(customDimensions.SampleStartTime)),
    EndTime = max(tolong(customDimensions.SampleEndTime))
    by Label = tostring(customDimensions.SampleLabel)
| extend s = 0
| union (
requests
| where name == testName
    and customDimensions.TestStartTime == TestStartTime
| summarize
    Samples = count(),
    Average = tolong(avg(duration)),
    (L50, L90, L95, L99)
        = percentiles(duration, 50, 90, 95, 99),
    Min = min(duration),
    Maximum = max(duration),
    ErrorCount = countif(success == false),
    StartTime = min(tolong(customDimensions.SampleStartTime)),
    EndTime = max(tolong(customDimensions.SampleEndTime))
| extend Label = 'TOTAL', s = 9
)
| extend
    tp = Samples / ((EndTime - StartTime) / 1000.0),
    KBPeriod = (EndTime - StartTime) * 1024 / 1000.0
| sort by s asc
| project
    Label, Samples, Average,
    Median = round(L50),
    ['90% Line'] = round(L90),
    ['95% Line'] = round(L95),
    ['99% Line'] = round(L99),
    Min, Maximum,
    ['Error %'] = strcat(round(ErrorCount * 100.0 / Samples, 2), '%'),
    ['Throughput'] = iif(tp < 1.0,
                        strcat(round(tp * 60, 1), '/min'),
                        strcat(round(tp, 1), '/sec')
                     )
| project-reorder
    Label, Samples, Average,
    ['Median'], ['90% Line'], ['95% Line'], ['99% Line'],
    Min, Maximum, ['Error %'], ['Throughput']
```

[image: Query for 1 test Results]

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to "compare" you need somehow to **distinguish** 2 different runs and I fail to see any metric you can use for that.

So the easiest option would be first running i.e. [Merge Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/) which will create an aggregate .jtl results file and then parse it using KQL.

Merge Results Tool can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, here is the Script for compare Results

Hope this help

```
requests
| where name == "{TestNameA}"
    and customDimensions.TestStartTime == "{TestStartTimeA}"
| summarize
    Samples_A = count(),
    Average_A = tolong(avg(duration)),
    (L95_A)
        = percentiles(duration, 95),
    Min_A = min(duration),
    Maximum_A = max(duration),
    ErrorCount_A = countif(success == false),
    StartTime = min(tolong(customDimensions.SampleStartTime)),
    EndTime = max(tolong(customDimensions.SampleEndTime))
    by Label = tostring(customDimensions.SampleLabel)
| extend s = 0
| join (
requests
| where name == "{TestNameB}"
    and customDimensions.TestStartTime == "{TestStartTimeB}"
| summarize
    Samples_B = count(),
    Average_B = tolong(avg(duration)),
    (L95_B)
        = percentiles(duration, 95),
    Min_B = min(duration),
    Maximum_B = max(duration),
    ErrorCount_B = countif(success == false),
    StartTime = min(tolong(customDimensions.SampleStartTime)),
    EndTime = max(tolong(customDimensions.SampleEndTime))
    by Label = tostring(customDimensions.SampleLabel)
| extend s = 1
) on Label
| sort by s asc
| project
    Label, Samples_A, Samples_B, Average_A, Average_B,
    ['95% Line_A'] = round(L95_A),
    ['95% Line_B'] = round(L95_B),
    Min_A, Min_B, Maximum_A, Maximum_B,
    ['Error_A %'] = strcat(round(ErrorCount_A * 100.0 / Samples_A, 2), '%'),
    ['Error_B %'] = strcat(round(ErrorCount_B * 100.0 / Samples_B, 2), '%')
| project-reorder
   Label, Samples_A, Samples_B, Average_A, Average_B,
    ['95% Line_A'], ['95% Line_B'], Min_A, Min_B, Maximum_A, Maximum_B, ['Error_A %'], ['Error_B %']
```

[Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdVRK.png)